# A basis in $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I want to find a basis in $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$.

What I've tried: $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a field extension, and $\pi \in \mathbb{R}$ is transcendental in $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(\pi) \simeq \mathbb{Q}(X)$ and, because $1, X, X^2, \dots, X^n, \dots$ is a basis in $\mathbb{Q}$, then $1, \pi, \pi^2, \pi^3, \dots, \pi^n, \dots$ is a basis in $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$. Is this true? Thanks!

Comment: How do you represent $\frac1{\pi}$ with your basis?

Comment: But you wrote $\Bbb Q(X)$, not $\Bbb Q[X]$.

Comment: @TedShifrin oh. Yes. I understand now. But what's a basis in $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ ?